# Biconnected components of a directed graph?

Tags: ds.algorithms, graph-theory, graph-algorithms

I am looking for an algorithm for computing the biconnected components of a strongly connected directed graph.

Comment: Have you checked [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biconnected_component)? ps: have you read our [FAQ]?

Comment: The Wikipedia article you link to is only about undirected graphs, so it doesn't answer Yossi's question.

Comment: @David, I see. Does biconnected component in the case of directed graphs mean that the graph will remain *strongly* connected after the removal of any vertex from the component?

Comment: That's what I would guess, and a search of Google scholar for "k-strongly-connected" finds some sources using that definition, but other sources using an edge connectivity version in which each nontrivial subset of the vertices has at least k incoming edges.